# Грамотно ли говорить "адекватный человек"?

Tags: употребление-слов

Адекватный — то есть соответствующий чему-то. То есть "адекватный" — это определение, а следовательно, должно быть и определяемое слово. А в словосочетании "адекватный человек" его нет. И чему этот человек адекватный?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Старый спор. Раньше "адекватный" действительно предполагало некий объект.
Теперь просто "адекватный" допускается как минимум на разговорном уровне. 
"Адекватный" при этом трактуется как "должный", "нормальный" или по умолчанию - "адекватный действительности, ситуации".

Нечто подобное ранее произошло со словом "соответствующий", и отчасти - "равный".

Comment: Вроде бы даже слово "нормальный" стали использовать не так давно - как дань моде на увлечение техникой, годах в 20-30-х прошлого века.

Comment: Возможно... Не задумывался. Но это не по теме. "Нормальный" не требует объекта (сравнения или принадлежности) и даже, похоже, не допускает его.

Comment: "Нормальность" требует объекта, разумеется. Нормальный – это перпендикулярный (есть, например, "нормаль" или "нормальные векторы"), а перпендикулярным просто так быть нельзя, надо быть перпендикулярным чему-то.

 Уверен, что "норма", "нормальность" в значениях "соответствующий критериям, правилам" и "обычный, среднестатистический" – это уже вторичное толкование, изначально это был именно мат. термин (который, возможно, пришел в математику/геометрию от названия чего-н прямого, перпендикулярного).

Comment: Спорно.  
Кстати, меня всегда удивляла некая перекличка:  
орт - единичный вектор, нормаль - перпендикуляр. Но в то же время   
ортогональный - перпендикулярный, норма - длина, соответственно, нормированный - единичной длины.

Comment: Нормированный – это не единичной длины. Ну и, к слову, нормальность, перпендикулярность и ортогональность не являются тождественными терминами, хотя в обычной жизни этим можно и пренебречь.

Comment: Конечно, слово "нормированный" многозначно, но "нормированный вектор" именно единичный.  
Главное, что "корень" **орт** связан как с длиной, так и с перпендикулярностью, и "корень" **норм** - тоже.  
И, конечно, слово "норма" произошло не из математики. Насчет "спорно" - просто форма вежливости.

Comment: Откуда же оно пришло? Предлагайте варианты. 

 "Орт" и "норм" – это слова из разных языков (греческий и латинский). Неудивительно, что их значения перекликаются.

Comment: Вынесу это в отдельный вопрос, здесь - оффтоп

Answer (score 4):

Адекватный человек – это "нормальный человек" или "вменяемый человек", то есть соответствующий определенным писаным и неписаным нормам, стереотипам поведения. Определяемое слово здесь "человек" (кто адекватный-то? Человек, это его определяют). Адекватное решение – туда же, то есть решение не противоречит здравому смыслу, является оптимальным, приемлемым.

Почему сейчас опускается дополнение, поясняющее, чему именно адекватен субъект? Например, могут сказать "Он поступил адекватно" вместо "Он поступил адекватно ситуации". Ну, тут все просто. Опускают это пояснение, потому что понятно, что подразумевают либо общие для всех нормы, либо нормы, критерии, требования обсуждаемой задачи, ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Поступок, поведение - это действия в какой-то среде с ее вызовами. И эти действия могут соответствовать или не соответствовать вызовам среды, то есть быть адекватными или неадекватными этим вызовам. Именно наличие причинно-следственной связи делает возможным применение слова "адекватный". Например, "адекватное наказание" или "адекватная оценка" предполагают наличие предшествующих действий, которые подверглись наказанию или оценке. А само слово "адекватный" подразумевает правильное соответствие следствия причине. "Неадекватный" - неправильное соответствие.
То есть если человек убил другого человека, а суд постановил наградить убийцу Орденом Красного Знамени, то можно говорить о неадекватности наказания

Человек - не действие в среде, не ответ и не следствие чего-либо. Поэтому применение слова "адекватный" здесь недопустимо.

Однажды в торговом центре одна женщина спросила у меня, есть ли в нем детский магазин, получив мое утверждение, она спросила: "А он, вообще, адекватный?"

Надеюсь, из моего объяснения становится понятно, что ни магазин, ни человек не могут быть адекватными или неадекватными.

Answer (score 0):

Адекватный человек гениален. Гениален, так как ровен в своих действиях всегда и при любых обстоятельствах. Среднему человеку с трудом случается быть адекватным обстановке; и тогда, если кратко выражаться, в этом отдельном эпизоде про него можно сказать - он адекватен. Имея при этом в виду, что смысл происходящего всем известен.