# Математическая терминология

Tags: этимология

В вопросе про [адекватность](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/23511/%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA) 
Мы с участником @Пересвет заспорили о математических словах

> орт - вектор единичной длины;
>   ортогональный - перпендикулярный;
>   норма - длина;
>   нормированный - связанный с длиной, в частности, приведенный к единичной длине;
>   нормаль - перпендикуляр.

Как видим, смыслы в этих словах переплелись достаточно прихотливо. Почему такая двойственность в этих корнях? Или слова **орт - ортогональный**, **норма - нормаль** не однокоренные и не восходят к одинаковым корням? Тогда тем более созвучие удивляет.

Comment: >Мы с участником @Пересвет заспорили о математических словах  
  
Напрасно Вы это сделали. Спорить о вкусе ананасов имеет смысл с теми, кто эти ананасы пробовал.

Comment: У меня есть подозрения, что математических ананасов я пробовал больше вашего.

Comment: У меня есть подозрения, что Вы их не пробовали вовсе.
Впрочем, не в этом дело. Я имел в виду, что троллей ананасами не кормят в принципе.

Comment: Если есть претензии к строгости изложения мыслей, то приводите примеры и аргументы. Пока что я вижу ваши безосновательные придирки к человеку, который зарабатывает на жизнь своим высшим техническим образованием.

Comment: >Если есть претензии к строгости изложения мыслей, то приводите примеры и аргументы  
  
Какие могут быть претензии к тому, чего нет? И после этого Вы позиционируете себя как математика?  
 
>Пока что я вижу ваши безосновательные придирки к человеку, который зарабатывает на жизнь своим высшим техническим образованием.  
   
~1. Вы тут на жизнь зарабатываете?   
~2. Это на какой же специальности учат объяснять свою значимость вкусом математических ананасов на лингвофоруме?   
~3. Если считаете придирки безосновательными, приводите примеры и аргументацию.

Comment: >>Какие могут быть претензии к тому, чего нет?
Нет строгости? Докажите.

>>Вы позиционируете себя как математика?
 Я не математик (не позиционировал себя так), но моя профессия тесно связана с математикой.

>> Вы тут на жизнь зарабатываете? 
 Нет, тут не зарабатываю, но род деятельности намекает.

>>Это на какой же специальности учат объяснять свою значимость вкусом математических ананасов на лингвофоруме? 
 На лингвофоруме обсуждаются мат. термины сейчас. Потому вкус мат. ананасов и важен.

Comment: Так, брейк, брейк! Моя тема, так что флудить в ней могу только я!

Comment: Наехал? Не заметила. Да и вопрос лингвистический, тут мы равны.

Comment: >> Если считаете придирки безосновательными, приводите примеры и аргументацию.

Придирки безосновательны, потому что вы так и не привели мне примеров "нестрогости" и аргументов по этому поводу, например.

>> Я про это:

 Про бревно и соринку рассказать?

>>Кстати, использование мелкой буквы позволяет думать, что он не одного меня имеет в виду.

 Я одного вас имел в виду. Что касается написания со строчной буквы: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_88

Comment: Чтобы освободить место, удалила некоторые свои комменты. @behemothus, можете удалить свои ответы на них, чтобы не висели без смысла. Кстати, Вы можете ничего на их месте не писать, Ваше мнение понятно.

Comment: Как скажете. Если Вы удалите и еще остальные, я возражать не буду.
А если еще и мультяру попросите удалить свой троллинг - я даже поблагодарю.

Answer (score 2):

> Или слова орт - ортогональный, норма - нормаль не однокоренные и не восходят к одинаковым корням?

Во-первых, следует разделять понятия однокоренных и родственных слов. В случае синхронистского подхода и для недавних заимствований это может быть существенно. Последнее, про заимствования, - это как раз про наши случаи.

Во-вторых, у специалистов русского (и не только) языка преобладает подход, что слова, родственные в языке-источнике, но пришедшие в русский ("язык-мишень") разными путями, родственными и - тем более - однокоренными не являются.

С этих позиций достаточно легко ответить и вопрос. Нормаль и нормальный стоит считать словами, родственными в латинском (и, возможно, в европейских), но не в русском. 
Ну и главное. В языках-источниках "орт" несет явно выраженный смысл "исходной правильности", "прямоты" (сравните: ортодокс и проч.), в то время как "норм" - обычности, повседневности, общепризнанности (английское normally -  в первую очередь "обычно", только в каком-то тридесятом значении "нормально"). Это, насколько понимаю, прослеживается весьма последовательно. В русском же, в силу сложившегося ранее значения "нормальный", эти понятия изрядно перемешались. 
Как-то так.

Comment: Про разницу однокоренных-родственных-имеющих общее происхождение слов я, конечно, понимаю, поэтому и упомянула (2 из 3) варианта. На самом деле интересен именно переход смыслов, почему у каждого корня они так разошлись, и почему у разных корней - сошлись? Может, действительно, есть связь:  
**прямая (линия) - прямо (стоящий) - вертикальный - перпендикулярный (земле)**.  
Но откуда сюда "прибилась" еще и длина? Это вообще непонятно!

Comment: >почему у каждого корня они так разошлись, и почему у разных корней - сошлись?  

Почему да почему... Божьим промыслом. Или попущением.   
Вы знаете, я не отвечаю на вопросы, начинающиеся с "почему", если у задавшего нет явного желания уяснить прямую причинно-следственную связь.

>Но откуда сюда "прибилась" еще и длина?   
  
Какая длина??? "Нормированный"? Так это от общелитературного значения, "нормы" вообще, норма - она и на африканской МТС - норма. Хоть в трудоднях, хоть в расходе бензина. Длина - дело тридесятое.

Comment: Длина – это не только количественная мера. Например, у прямоугольника есть **длина** и ширина, такое разделение тесно связано с **протяженностью** в пространстве.

Comment: >Ну, в понятие "орт"... его произвольной длины?  
  
По всем трем вопросам. Я вижу здесь прямую аналогию с общелитературным, а не сугубо математическими значениями понятия "норма", а следовательно, не вижу и причин для какой-то любопытности использования понятия.

Comment: Ну, не видите и не надо. Ваше мнение понятно. Может, кто еще набежит, подкинет идейку.  
Кстати, слово "орт" к общелитературным ну никак не относится.

Answer (score 0):

Ортогональный – это буквально "прямоугольный". Думаю, не стоит объяснять связь прямого угла с перпендикулярностью? С другой стороны, достаточна очевидна связь вектора (направления + длины, если грубо) и "прямоты", "горизонтальности".

Со словами "норма"-"нормаль" история та же. Норма – это длина и прямота, нормаль – "нормальная линия", то есть под прямым углом.

Comment: Прямота, длина, протяженность, правильность, линия – эти понятия тесно связаны, я считаю.

Comment: То есть вы считаете, что название угла "прямой" - это калька с аналогичных греко-латинско-европейских терминов? Потому что тут прямизна другая (по крайней мере, для математика). Наверное, можно как-то связать через "вертикаль", "прямостояние". Но тут еще надо думать.

Comment: Ну, мы имеем пример М. Ломоносова, который заменил триангул треугольником, а аддицию – сложением. 

 Связывать с прямостоянием и вертикалью – это верный путь. Если палку воткнуть в землю под прямым углом, она будет выглядеть ровно, будет прямо стоять. С другой стороны, прямой путь – это наикратчайший путь, что тоже намекает.