# Насколько востребована адекватность?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Попался на глаза вопрос [Грамотно ли говорить “адекватный человек”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/23511/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA), вспомнил давешний спор на кухне.

Вопрос такой был -- можно ли говорить, что в обществе есть чёткий запрос на адекватность? Или, снижая пафос, можно ли как-то оценить динамику употребления слова -- реже употребляется, столько же, чаще?

Есть такой сервис -- Google Trends: показывает частоту употребления слова в оцифрованных книгах. Если вбить туда слово "адекватный", то видно, что частота употребления растёт. Непонятно правда, этот рост большой или маленький -- нужна какая-то сравнительная величина. (Это ещё не самый сложный вопрос: по-хорошему нужно как-то отделить адекватность человека от других адекватностей: слово-то достаточно широко может использоваться)

Допустим, почти навскидку взял и сравнил [динамику слов "космический" и "адекватный"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%2C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=12&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%3B%2Cc0): получается сравнимый рост, разве что у слова "космический" прямо-таки резкая "свечка", а у слова "адекватный" абсолютный рост практически такой же, но не такой резкий. А сравнение с "коллайдером" (слово 2008 года) ещё более показательно. А до слова "коррупция" не дотянуло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Насколько объективны подобные сравнения? Или это уровень "лингвистики" у юмориста Задорнова? Есть ли в арсенале лингвистики какие-то инструменты, которые убедительно могут показать подобные *долгосрочные* тренды (много больше чем интервал в год)? Проводились ли подобные исследования и если проводились, то какие слова в лидерах десятилетия?

PS Возможно, у меня достаточно большой вопрос. Если так -- можно тезисно ответить или привести ссылки, что можно почитать на эту тему.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что в обществе  есть чёткий запрос на адекватность. **Адекватный человек - это герой нашего времени.** Какие же они, адекватные люди, ну вот, например, такие:

(1)  Ты-то **супер-мега-адекватный парняга,** ни ради чего под бульдозер не полезешь.

(2) Судя по моим впечатлениям, человек он **вполне адекватный**, журналист грамотный и источники у него в отрасли отнюдь не рядовые и весьма информированные.

**АДЕКВАТНЫЙ**  [от лат. adaequatus - приравненный]. **Книжн.** Вполне **соответствующий** чему-л. (условиям, обстановке и т.п.); верный, **совпадающий с ожидаемым.** А-ые реакции. А-ое лечение (соответствующее болезни, точное лечение). А. ребёнок (о ребёнке с верными реакциями, понятиями).

Слово "адекватный" появилось в 20 веке в качестве медицинского термина (например: **реакция на раздражитель оказалась адекватной**), но затем получило широкое распространение во всех областях жизни (дипломатия, политика, техника, образование и др.) и стало не книжным, а вполне нейтральным.

**Чем объяснить популярность слова?** Жизнь настолько стремительна, что у нас просто у нас нет времени на долгое обдумывание своих поступков, и тогда на смену им приходят правильные или неправильные реакции на раздражитель. Поведение должно быть ожидаемым, в противном случае мы имеем дело с неадекватным человеком.

Кстати, у слова "адекватный" есть **синонимы**: верный, вменяемый, естественный,  здравомыслящий, идентичный, нормальный, обычный, правильный, равноценный, соответственный и др. Думаю, что **для оценки востребованности слова** лучше сравнивать изменение частотности употребления слов из синонимичного ряда.